# Delete ALL custom cell styles EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, styles

Is it possible to delete ALL the custom/created cell styles in a workbook ? Just leaving the default styles.

Without having to delete them all one by one

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this small VBA macro:

```
Sub StyleKiller()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long

    With ActiveWorkbook
        N = .Styles.Count
        For i = N To 1 Step -1
            If Not .Styles(i).BuiltIn Then .Styles(i).Delete
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

This resolves the ***Builtin*** vs ***Custom*** issue.  Note we run the loop *backwards* to avoid corrupting the loop index.

Comment: Useful one,,, ☺

Comment: For some reason, when deleting the first non built in style it displayed a generic error message. Andreas' solution below worked though.

Answer (score 9):

To simply remove all without using `INDEX`, try the below:

```
Sub StyleKiller()
    Dim st As Style
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each st In ActiveWorkbook.Styles
      If Not st.BuiltIn Then
        st.Delete
      End If
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for answering ! its a LOT simpler than my version, I will test later, and if it works I will accept as correct answer

Comment: Using `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0` is IMHO bad coding style. You can safely remove those, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

All of the above works but our work pc's are quite dated so the macro's kept crashing. For some reason a lot of the files have hundreds of cell styles which slows down the docs.

My solution turned out to be easy and quick.

Select all the worksheets in your workbook and copy them to a new book. This maintains all the external links and formats and everything but the styles does not copy across.

Save your new workbook over the old one (Close the old one first).

Comment: welcome to super user and thanks for your answer, always good for a non vba alternative !

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this wasn't as hard to do as I first thought.

Bit messy as I don't often use vba; but this code will roll back to just the default styles:

```
Sub DefaultStyles()
   Dim MyBook As Workbook
   Dim tempBook As Workbook
   Dim CurStyle As Style
   Set MyBook = ActiveWorkbook
   On Error Resume Next
   For Each CurStyle In MyBook.Styles
      Select Case CurStyle.Name
         Case "20% - Accent1", "20% - Accent2", _
               "20% - Accent3", "20% - Accent4", "20% - Accent5", "20% - Accent6", _
               "40% - Accent1", "40% - Accent2", "40% - Accent3", "40% - Accent4", _
               "40% - Accent5", "40% - Accent6", "60% - Accent1", "60% - Accent2", _
               "60% - Accent3", "60% - Accent4", "60% - Accent5", "60% - Accent6", _
               "Accent1", "Accent2", "Accent3", "Accent4", "Accent5", "Accent6", _
               "Bad", "Calculation", "Check Cell", "Comma", "Comma [0]", "Currency", _
               "Currency [0]", "Explanatory Text", "Good", "Heading 1", "Heading 2", _
               "Heading 3", "Heading 4", "Input", "Linked Cell", "Neutral", "Normal", _
               "Note", "Output", "Percent", "Title", "Total", "Warning Text"
         Case Else
            CurStyle.Delete
      End Select
   Next CurStyle
   Set tempBook = Workbooks.Add
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   MyBook.Styles.Merge Workbook:=tempBook
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   tempBook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually I like the way you loop over `Styles` rather than my looping over an index.

Comment: Will have problems here, deleting a collection forwards.

Comment: @AJD Hi, thanks for your comment, what problems could be caused from this ?

Comment: @PeterH: deleting forwards means that items in the collection are renumbered. For example, in the loop, `j` is = 1 and then you `Delete(1)`. (2) moves to (1), but `j` increments to 2, so the next step is `Delete(2)`, which is the old (3). `For Each` is an enumerating loop, so the same logic is used. There was a good explanation on StackOverflow somewhere - I can't find it, but these also explain:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858718/word-vba-shaperange-delete-unexpected-behavior/18859393#18859393 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45585393/vba-loop-and-delete-issue

Comment: @AJD Thanks for the info, the macro itself works as intended, I have used it on several workbooks since I posted it back in Feb

Comment: @PeterH: Then that is by luck, rather than by design.

Comment: @AJD please do explain, I am not good with VBA so if I can learn something that would be great. I know you have said about `j is = 1` but I do not use that anywhere in the macro

Comment: @PeterH, I have used `j` because the autocorrect in this box keeps capitalising `I` on me! Have a read of those links I put in my comment, they have answers that discuss why.

Comment: Microsoft has this exact same code, albeit with comments and more directions https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-programmatically-reset-a-workbook-to-default-styles-36e94af7-d185-68fb-3962-0882a5260132

Comment: Note that "Hyperlinks" is arguably a default style that should also be preserved. It is not present in a fresh new workbook, but automagically appears if you make a cell hyperlink.

Answer (score 2):

The issue of custom styles is also discussed in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213904

I found that installing the free "XLStyles Tool" from MS Store as suggested in the KB article was a very convenient way to delete the custom styles.

Comment: Definitely, the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple way.
step-1 Rename excel file as .zip
step-2. Extract file in same folder "Extract Files Here"
Step-3. Open Styles.xml with note pad.
Step-5 Select from  to  and delete.
Step-6 Save file, exit from subdirectory and convert all files to ZIP
Step-7 Rename .zip as .xlsx
Step-8 Open with excel and enjoy

Comment: thanks for your answer ! i wouldn't say this is a simple way tho :)